# Getting a windows mobile 6.5 device to connect to a 2012 mssql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, windows-mobile-6.5

I'm trying to get a barcode scanner to connect to a MSSQL server. From what i could find it seems as though only VS2008 is compatible with the device. But Windows 2008 cannot connect to a msSQL 2012 server.

I'm looking for either a solution to be able to connect Visual Studios 2008 to a 2012 MySQL server Or a way to make windows 6.5 mobile compatible with anything else (ex Visual studio 2015)

When I attempt to connect via 2008 it gives me a SQL client error, When i use the VS2015 version it gives an error about Windows.forums. Even though i made sure to include it as a reference.

I have tried changing the .net compatibility and changed it to c# 3.0  but nothing seems to work.

Edit: this code won't connect to MSSQL 2012 server in VS 2008.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace lasttestytesty
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string connetionString = null;
        SqlConnection connection;
        SqlCommand command;
        string sql = null;

        connetionString = //deleted// 
        sql = "update CUSTOMERS set SALARY =" + updater + " where age= 27;";

        connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            command.Dispose();
            connection.Close();
            MessageBox.Show(" ExecuteNonQuery in SqlCommand executed !!");
        }
```

Comment: You can connect to SQL Server with VS2008.  It just that you cannot use the built in GUI (Data Source) to make connection.  Done it lots of times.  You need to use the SQLClient class.  See msdn : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I get the error "cannot connect to any server post 2005." Im trying to connect to a 2012 server  Edit: I used  data.sqlclient to try and connect as well. it just said it failed to connect.

Comment: The issue is the connection string.  Common problem.  the connection string I like is : "Server=myServerName\myInstanceName;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated Security=True;" Use  SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) which comes with SQL Server.  The Server instance can be found on the login page of SSMS.  The Initial Catalog can be found using the SSMS explorer and checking under the databases for your database.